# Find out which environment variables my node project is using?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

We have currently a single repo with about 20 packages in it.

In the root folder we have one .env file with a lot of env-vars in it. 
Some of the packages have there own .env file extending or overwriting the global one.

I am currently trying to write a script which exactly shows which package uses which env-var and compare them to the ones in the .env files and on the actually AWS-instances. This is only the first step to clean up this mess.

Is there a way to find out which package is using an environment variable?
Currently i have something like this (simplified version):

```
grep -rhoE 'process\.env\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+' $$ROOT_DIR/packages
```

With that I get about 180 variables. But since environment variables can also be destructured this 'script' won't fetch those variables.

Is there another more reliable way of getting all used env-vars? Something like a node module?

Going through the code by hand is not feasible since it is just too much code and this step should be automated.

Comment: As in, you want to know which dependency is using which env variable, so that you can delete unused entries in .env file?

Comment: Yes and to make sure that we have all needed env variables setted in our AWS-instances. We are aware that this is already a situation. This is the first step to clean this up and maybe use some tool to handle the env-vars.